# Como disparar emails com data marcada em php?

Tags: php, mysql, email

Tenho de criar um sistema em PHP para disparar emails para clientes em certos dias do mês ou em dias contados. Como posso fazer isso ? Alguma sugestão ??

Comment: Você pode verificar no php qual é a data, e chamar uma função para envio.. eu faria assim...

Comment: Fiz uma pesquisa rápida na net e encontrei vários posts sobre esse assunto. De antemão, não como resposta, veja se este [link] (http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/sistema-em-php-de-envio-de-newsletter-com-pausa-de-lote) te ajuda.

Comment: Aqui tb tem algo relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com[Envio de email programado com PHP](/q/65940/) - Caso seu OS seja diferente, edite a pergunta e acrescente todos os detalhes relevantes, para que em caso de reabertura não fique ampla demais, nem pouco clara.

Comment: ALgumas maneiras ---> 1-vc pode usar cronJobs em php diretamente (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428), vc pode usar js ,setTimeout, ABORDAGEM MENOS INDICADA, só para iniciantes, ou usar uma cronJob do windows que chama um arquivo php que vai disparar seus e-mails